# [Vue warn]:A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function

Tags: laravel, typescript, pagination, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Can anyone help me please, I’m trying to get the plug-in Laravel-Vue-pagination working on my nuxt 3(typescript) project.

nuxt.config.ts

```
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/vueLaravelPagination',
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ['LaravelVuePagination'],
  },
  vue: {
    compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: tag => ['LaravelVuePagination'].includes(tag)
    }
  }
```

plugins/vueLaravelPagination.ts

```
import LaravelVuePagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxt) => {
    nuxt.vueApp.use(LaravelVuePagination)
  
})
```

I get a warning when I try to use the pager as follows and describe it as follows. I do not know how to solve this problem. Can someone please help me?

```
<Pagination
   :data="data"
 @changePage="onAccess" />
```

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function.
```

Comment: It looks like something is not Vue3 compatible here.

Comment: https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination　It's compatible with vue3.

Comment: I have the same issue with 'vue-draggable-next'. Haven't got any fix yet

Answer (score 2):

I use click-outside-vue3' as directive with Nuxt3. Had the same issue.
The reason was that I had:
`import ClickOutside from 'click-outside-vue3/src/v-click-outside'`
instead of `import ClickOutside from 'click-outside-vue3'` in plugin file.

The way I use this Vue3 plugin in Nuxt3:

plugins/vClickOutside.ts:

```
import ClickOutside from 'click-outside-vue3/src/v-click-outside'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ClickOutside, {
    })
})
```

and also in component where directive is used:

```
import vClickOutside from 'click-outside-vue3'
...
...
directives: {
   clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive
 },
```

And I do not register the plugin in nuxt.config.ts file.

Know there is a better way using "script setup". But it also work